# Filling across a specified dimension of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a relatively common situation arising where I need to fill across a given dimension of an array. For example, if I have an array:

```
example_array = np.zeros((2,3,4), dtype=bool)
example_array[:, 1, [1,3]] = True
```

which then has contents:

```
array([[[False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]]])
```

I would like to fill the contents across a given dimension - for example, if I want to fill across dimension 1, I could do this:

```
output = np.cumsum(example_array, axis=1, dtype=bool)
output = np.cumsum(output[:, ::-1, :], axis=1, dtype=bool)
```

giving me the desired output:

```
array([[[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]],

       [[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]]])
```

Does anyone have a neater/more elegant way of doing this? I am doing this on boolean arrays, so whether or not the filling operation involves summing across the other axes, or just copying the values from a given element (in this case element 1 of dimension 1) across, I don't mind.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/assistance.

Comment: Usually we think of `fill` as assigning a fill value, e.g. scalar `True` to all or part of the array.  e.g. `example_array[:, 0, :] = 0` or `example_array[...] = example_array[0,0,:]`

Comment: @hpaulj - Yes - I thought it perhaps wasn't quite the right term. Not sure what is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A memory-efficient solution would be to use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to have a viewed output -

```
In [14]: a # input array
Out[14]: 
array([[[False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]]])

In [15]: np.broadcast_to(a.any(1,keepdims=True), a.shape)
Out[15]: 
array([[[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]],

       [[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]]])
```

If you need the output to have its own memory space, append with `.copy()` there.

Alternatively, we can use `np.repeat` -

```
In [63]: np.repeat(a.any(1,keepdims=True) ,a.shape[1],axis=1)
Out[63]: 
array([[[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]],

       [[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]]])
```

Comment: thanks, that seems like a neat and efficient way to go. Much appreciated.